# React js redux how to update state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a redux state in reducer as follows:
posts:

```
[0] post_id:1010
    post_title:"Title1" 
    post_comments [0] id=1 Title="Some text0"
                  [1] id=2 Title="Some text1"

[1] post_id:1011
    post_title:"Title2" 
    post_comments: [0] id=11 Title="Some text Comments0"
                   [1] id=22 Title="Some text Comments1"
```

When user inserts new post comments, how can I add to post comments if I have response as id=33 Title="Loreim Ispum". I need to add it to post_id:1011 which also I have in response.
I currently tried like in reducer:

```
   items = state.posts;
   items[key].comments =  items[key].comments.concat(action.data);

   return Object.assign({}, state, {
        asyncLoading: true,
        asyncError: null,
        posts:items
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you determining, to which element in array, you need to concat it

Comment: I can get both post_id:1011 or post[1] ie key. I just need to append it as 2 item in the post_comments. 
    post_comments: [0] id=11 Title="Some text Comments0"
                   [1] id=22 Title="Some text Comments1"
     [2] id=33 Title="Loreim Ispum"

Comment: What is `comments` here `items[key].comments.concat(action.data)` ? Is that `post_comments`?

Comment: return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post => ((post.post_id === action.post_id) ? {
          ...post,
          post_comments: [...post.post_comments, action.comment]
        } : post)),
      };

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of spread operator and update like

```
return {
    ...state,
       asyncLoading: true,
       asyncError: null,
       posts: {
           ...state.posts.slice(0, post_index),
           {
                ...state.posts[post_index],
                post_comments: [...state.posts[post_index].post_comments, action.payload]
           },
           ...state.posts.slice(post_index 
+ 1),
       }
   }
```